# Call model function - Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, function, model

I have been approaching Laravel for a few days. My simple question, considering that I have done various tests, but nothing, is how can I recover in the "Controller" a function created in the "Model" (which is located in the `App/`, if I'm not mistaken, isn't it?), And then show it in the views?

Let me explain better, I have to show the total of my posts (as a number), then I create a query in the model that counts the total of the posts, once this is done I create the instance in the controller and pass it to the view.

Probably I'm wrong in the syntax, I attach an example:

`App/Post.php`

```php
public function totalActivePost() { 
    $count = DB::table('post')->get(); 
    return $count->count(); 
}
```

`App/Http/Controllers`

```php
$modelPost = new Post; 
$totalActivePost = $modelPost->totalActivePost();
return view('index', 
                ['totalActivePost' => $totalActivePost]
           );
```

While in the view I call then `{{ @totalActivePost }}`

Unfortunately nothing, what am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller all you need is this:

```
$totalActivePost = Post::count();
//...
return view('index')->with(['posts' => $posts, 'set' => $set, 'totalActivePost' => $totalActivePost]);
```

Then access it in your view `index` with:

```
 {{ $totalActivePost }}
```

Or you can utilize Local scope in your model, this allows you to reuse the query all throughout your application:

```
 public function scopeCountPosts($query)
 {
    return $query->get()->count();
 }
```

Now you can access it in your controllers like so:

```
$totalActivePost = Post::CountPosts();
```

Comment: Error: Undefined variable: totalActivePost in index views

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `{{ @totalActivePost  }}` you should use `{{ $totalActivePost }}`

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```
public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth');
        $this->modelPost = new Post;
    }

    public function index()
        {

            // get settings
            $set = DB::table('settings')
                ->where('id', 1)
                ->first();

            // other code...

             $totalActivePost = Post::count();

            return view('index', 
                        ['posts' => $posts],
                        ['set' => $set],
                        ['totalActivePost' => $totalActivePost]
                       );

        }
```

**Views index.blade**

```
{{ $totalActivePost }}
```